# MonoDroid project in a solution that contains a windows 7 phone project?

Tags: android, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, xamarin.android

I have a VS 2010 solution that has a windows 7 phone project in it.

I added a default monoandroid project and when I try to deploy it(the emulator dialog does appear)

I get this error

```
" (SignAndroidPackage target) (1) ->
(_CompileAndroidPackage target) -> 
  monodroid : error 1: Evaluation version requires targeting the shared runtime. [C:\A\B\AndroidApplication1.csproj]

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.87
```

If I unload the windows 7 phone project I lose the ability to deploy it.

They are currently share nothing. I just want them in the same project.

Comment: Lose the ability to deploy the MonoDroid or the WP7 project?

Comment: @Dennis Delimarsk - Well if I unload the the WP7 project and right click on the MonoDroid project the deploy button is gone. If I load the WP7 back in and the deploy button is back. WP7 will run still it's just the MonoDroid project that can't. I am not sure if it thinks I am trying to deploy to WP7 emulator or what.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you change the `AndroidApplication1` project options to disable the shared runtime, and/or do a Release build? You can check the shared runtime by viewing the Project Properties, going to the Mono Android Options tab, and ensuring that the "Use Shared Runtime" checkbox is checked.

Release builds always disable the shared runtime by default, so performing a Release build could also be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create a blank solution and sequentially add projects to it. Then see if you have similar deployment problems. I had problems before with solutions that were created as a part of a platform-specific project.